# Displaying data based on a selection in TreeView

Tags: c#, xaml, datagrid, treeview

I am fairly new to this process, and this seems like a question that may have been answered somewhere, but I am unable to find what I am looking for.

In my application I have a section with a TreeView, displaying a tree.

Next to that TreeView, I wan to to use a Data Grid, with 2 columns, where column 1 contains labels (Name:), and column 2 contains the textboxes related to the labels (Bob Smith), which will allow the user to change (i.e.  Name:  Bob Smith).

The data that gets populated into the data grid is variable in length, but those labels to textboxes are 1:1.

Using the simple TreeView code I posted, what follows the = is the data.

````
Level 1 = (t)
Level 2.1 = (a, b, c)
Level 2.2 = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
Level 3.1 = (q, w)
Level 2.3 = (m, n, o, p)



```
<Window x:Class="WpfTutorialSamples.TreeView_control.TreeViewSample"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="TreeViewSample" Height="200" Width="250">
    <Grid Margin="10">
        <TreeView>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Level 1" IsExpanded="True">
                <TreeViewItem Header="Level 2.1" />
                <TreeViewItem Header="Level 2.2" IsExpanded="True">
                    <TreeViewItem Header="Level 3.1" />
                </TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Level 2.3" />
            </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```
````

Question is how to display the data into the datagrid from selecting something on the TreeView?

Or rather, when I click on for example

level 2.1 of the Tree, the information pertaining and contained within 2.1 is displayed in the Datagrid, and when I click 2.3, the screen refreshes and displays the data in 2.3?

Comment: Whenever you take a tree and flatten to a table you need to be able to get the parent from the child and the child from the parent.  You can do this either adding a column with the level (2.1) or giving each node a unique number and then have columns ID and Parent ID.  Using the level is a little harder because you have to parse the levels from the number like 2.1.

Comment: I usually create my own custom class the inherits the TreeViewItem like  MYTreeViewItem : TreeViewItem.  Then I can add my custom object to class and write a method for displaying.

Comment: What I am talking about is when I click on any node in the TreeView it displays information relevant to the node, the node is populated from parsing a file.  Each node has a variable field of information.

I guess is the question is more along of the lines of how to dynamically create labels and text boxes  in a datagrid based of a selection of an item in a TreeView.  will I need to set the Labels and positions in the C# code and have the XAML code ref that c# or is there something else I cna use to get hat done?

Comment: Why do you need it dynamic?  The columns of the DataGrid should always be the same and the rows will get filled based on the TreeView Node you click.

Comment: I did not see your second comment there, sorry if that caused confusion jdweng.

In short...

1.  Create a class that inherits the node.  2.  For each item (data section) I want just add it to the row and column.

On the XAML side, is there anything special I eed to do, or is all this handled directly within the C# code?

Comment: I have added row and column number lots of times to an inherited class.  As long as the properties are public you should be able to treat the custom TreeViewItem exactly like the standard TreeViewItem.

Comment: Gotcha and thank you

I got the idea, and this question can be closed.  I'm considering it answered, I don't know where that would be recorded at but there it is.

Comment: I sometimes create  List<List<MyTreeViewItem>> items so I can easily go to the row/column items[row, col]  The list does not duplicate the MyTreeViewItem instance but just creates a link to the existing item.